# Performance measuring

Tags: java, eclipse, performance-testing

I wanted to know if there is a way to measure the overhead of a specific function or even the running time of an application in Eclipse (with the capability to run the test for arbitrary times to get the average time).
I have a code that should be executed in Eclipse therefore looking for such a thing. I know that we have Jmeter in Netbeans and I'm looking for something similar in Eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. they all seem suitable I'll try them and if further information is needed or even if I have questions I'll let you know.

Comment: Another choice is JMeter and its quite a good tool for profiling and can be used in both Eclipse and Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experiences with [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). It should be precise enough to give usable data even when you run your function only once, depending on how you set it up. It also optionally integrates with Eclipse.

It's not free, but there's a fully functioning trial available.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) before and it worked quite good to me.

It quite easy to use, just open the DDMS view in eclipse and look for the icon with three arrows with a red dot (Start Method Profiling). Click the icon and test your app as you want. When you are done click on stop. The trace should open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

http://www.jvmmonitor.org/

It's called Java Monitor and comes as an eclipse plugin. You can install it from eclipse market place.

Comment: I have two choices (I'm looking for free profilers): JVM monitor and TPTP, although JProfiler is a good choice.
I wanted to know which one is better for getting the over head? Can we say that TPTP is more accurate? I want to test my Thesis and I want to use an appropriate tool. (If needed I might use JProfiler)